Customize button positions with linking arrows to demonstrate a hierarchy in R Shiny
I'm interested in demonstrating how two different sets of geography boundaries fit in between a higher level and lower level geography that they have in common. I want to do this by organizing the buttons in relation to each other and connect with arrows. Along the lines of this:

I've made a demonstration shiny app showing what I've tried to accomplish using bslibs layout_columns() and cards(), however at this point I'm stuck.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

ui <- page_fluid(
  layout_columns(
    card(
      card(
        actionButton("btn1", "Button One")
      ),
      layout_columns(
        card(
          actionButton("btn2", "Button Two"),
          actionButton("btn3", "Button Three")
        ),
        card(
          actionButton("btn4", "Button Four")
        )
      ),
      card(
        actionButton("btn5", "Button Five")
      )
    )
    ,
    card(
      p("Space for some important text")
    ),
    col_widths = c(3,9)
  ),
  layout_columns(
    leafletOutput("main_map",
                  width = "50vw",
                  height = "30vw")
  )
)


shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {
  
  file <- system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf")
  btn1 <- read_sf(file) %>% 
    st_transform(crs = 4326)
  btn2 <- btn1 %>% filter(NAME %in% c("Ashe", "Alleghany"))
  btn3 <- btn1 %>% filter(NAME %in% c("Camden", "Gates"))
  btn4 <- btn1 %>% filter(NAME %in% c("Edgecombe", "Orange"))
  btn5 <- btn1 %>% filter(NAME %in% c("Durham", "Martin"))
  
  output$main_map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Voyager', group = "Simple Street Map",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
                       ) %>% 
      addPolygons(data = btn1,
                  group = "Button One",
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = ~NAME,
                  opacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~NAME,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3
                  ) %>% 
      addLayersControl(
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
        )
  })
  
  selectedData <- reactiveValues(dataset = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$btn1, {
    selectedData <- btn1
    
    leafletProxy("main_map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = selectedData,
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = ~NAME,
                  opacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~NAME,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn2, {
    selectedData <- btn2
    
    leafletProxy("main_map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = selectedData,
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = ~NAME,
                  opacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~NAME,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn3, {
    selectedData <- btn3
    
    leafletProxy("main_map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = selectedData,
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = ~NAME,
                  opacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~NAME,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn4, {
    selectedData <- btn4
    
    leafletProxy("main_map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = selectedData,
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = ~NAME,
                  opacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~NAME,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn5, {
    selectedData <- btn5
    
    leafletProxy("main_map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(data = selectedData,
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = ~NAME,
                  opacity = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~NAME,
                  fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
  
})

This is how it currently looks for me. Generally the positioning is fine, but could be better. I don't have a clue how to add arrows at the moment. I will keep searching for now.
I am also open to solutions using CSS as I have a stylesheet already going for my dashboard.
Note: In this example the buttons when clicked just highlight whatever sections of the map, I didn't want to figure out a fully fledged hierarchy!


Have you considered using one of the many libraries available to display hierarchical data in {shiny}?

You've been given good suggestions to libraries that might dynamically solve this issue for you; if however you are doing a couple of static representations; you would perhaps go a lo-tech route, and simply get hold of some arrow images (png or svg) and arrange them into your ui as static assets. Its worth considering at least.

@ismirsehregal thank you for the link! There is so much stuff there I was unaware of!

One way would be to create a custom visualization with r2d3. Admittedly, maybe not the easiest solution, but for sure the most bespoke one.
Idea is that you create a button hierarchy (eventually a button is nothing else than a rectangle with some hover effects), lay it out in a tree format and notify shiny when you click a button.
I conveniently used the tree layout of d3, which does most of the positioning, with 2 minor differences compared to your example:

We cannot define more than one parent. Thus, if there is a second parent, we need to add this visual manually.
Because each node has by design only one parent hte depth is well defined, nodes of the same depth are placed on the same line. That is node CLHA (41) is placed in the same line as its sibling node LHA (89) and not between LHA (89) and HSDA (16). The same holds true with regard to the horizontal placement. We could manually work around that, but this would require quite some effort.

Code speaks a thousand words, so here we go:
app.R
library(shiny)
library(r2d3)
library(tibble)
library(here)

btn_hr <- list(
  tree = tibble(label = c("CHSA (231)", "LHA (89)", "CLHA (41)", 
                          "HSDA (16)", "HA (5)"),
                parent = c(NA, "CHSA (231)", "CHSA (231)", "LHA (89)", "HSDA (16)")),
  add_lnks = tibble(from = c("CLHA (41)"), to = "HA (5)")
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    d3Output("button_hierarchy")   
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("dbg")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$button_hierarchy <- renderD3(
    r2d3(
      btn_hr,
      script = here("button_hierarchy.js"),
      options = list(id = "button_hierarchy")
    )
  )
  
  output$dbg <- renderPrint({
    input$button_hierarchy_btn
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

btn_hr defines the button hierarchy. Each button (except the root) has one (and exactly one) parent. To allow for multiple parents (that is additional lines), we define a second data frame which defines additional links.
button_hierarchy.js
// !preview r2d3 data=list(tree = tibble::tibble(label = c("CHSA (231)", "LHA (89)", "CLHA (41)", "HSDA (16)", "HA (5)"), parent = c(NA, "CHSA (231)", "CHSA (231)", "LHA (89)", "HSDA (16)")), add_lnks = tibble::tibble(from = c("CLHA (41)"), to = "HA (5)")), viewer ="browser"

const data_traf = {
  tree: HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(data.tree),
  add_lnks: HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(data.add_lnks)
};

console = d3.window(svg.node()).console;
const boxes = { width: 150, height: 40, radius: 4 };
const marker = { width: 6, height: 6 };
const root = d3.stratify()
  .id((d) => d.label)
  .parentId((d) => d.parent)(data_traf.tree);
const tree = d3.tree().size([width, height * .8])(root);

const rng = d3.reduce(root, (current, next) => 
  [Math.min(current[0], next.y - boxes.height / 2), 
   Math.max(current[1], next.y + boxes.height / 2)], 
   [Infinity, -Infinity]
);

const upside_down = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(rng)
  .range(rng.reverse());

function styleButton(selection) {
  selection.append('rect')
      .attr('x', (d) => d.x - boxes.width / 2)
      .attr('y', (d) => upside_down(d.y + boxes.height / 2))
      .attr('width', boxes.width)
      .attr('height', boxes.height)
      .attr('rx', boxes.radius);
  selection.append('text')
    .text((d) => d.data.label)
    .attr('x', (d) => d.x)
    .attr('y', (d) => upside_down(d.y))
    .attr('dy', '.35em');
  selection.on('click', function(evt, d) {
    if (typeof Shiny !== 'undefined') {
      const id = options.id + '_btn';
      Shiny.setInputValue(id, d.data.label, {priority: 'event'});
    } else {
      console.log(`Button ${d.data.label} clicked`);
    }
  })
}

function drawPath(source, target) {
  const h = boxes.height;
  const d = target.depth - source.depth - 1;
  const gap = target.y - target.parent.y - h;
  const y0 = source.y + h / 2;
  const y1 = target.y - h / 2; 
  const ym = y0 + (gap + h) * d + gap / 2;
  const points = [
    [source.x, upside_down(y0)],
    [source.x, upside_down(ym)],
    [target.x, upside_down(ym)],
    [target.x, upside_down(y1 - marker.height / 2)]
  ];
  return points.map((p) => p.join(',')).join(' ');
}

svg.append('defs')
  .append('marker')
  .attr('id', 'arrow')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 10 10')
  .attr('refX', 5)
  .attr('refY', 5)
  .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse')
  .attr('markerWidth', marker.width)
  .attr('markerHeight', marker.height)
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z');

const tree_container = svg.append('g')
  .classed('tree', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (boxes.height + 5) + ')');

tree_container.append('g')
  .classed('links', true);
  
tree_container.append('g')
  .classed('nodes', true);

svg.select('g.nodes')
  .selectAll('g.button')
  .data(root.descendants())
  .join('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .call(styleButton);

svg.select('g.links')
  .selectAll('polyline.link')
  .data(root.links())
  .join('polyline')
  .classed('link', true)
  .attr('points', (d) => drawPath(d.source, d.target))
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');
  
svg.select('g.links')
  .selectAll('polyline.add-link')
  .data(data_traf.add_lnks)
  .join('polyline')
  .classed('link add-link', true)
  .attr('points', (d) => {
    const source = root.find((n) => n.data.label == d.from);
    const target = root.find((n) => n.data.label == d.to);
    return drawPath(source, target);
  })
  .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');

N.B. The comment in the beginning is a convenient way of testing the visualization also outside of shiny. The console hack is simply there to route debug messages to the standard console instead of showing them as popup.
As said, we use a tree layout to place the buttons. In the click handler, we tell shiny which button was clicked. To make name clashes as unlikely as possible, I passed the id of d3Output as a user option to d3 to create the name for the shiny input we want to listen to button_hierarchy_btn (i.e. _btn appended to the id of the output element). Theoretically, we could grab this information from the DOM, but as we want to use the shadow-root  functionality of d3, I am not aware of how to get this information from element outside  the shadow-dom.
button_hierarchy.css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button > rect {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.button:hover > rect {
  fill: #e6e6e6;
  stroke: #adadad;
}

.button > text {
  color: black;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

Screenshot

